# how do i get to restrict access to my folders

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

am using codeigniter to build a website with a lot of image galleries , i store the images in folders ,but i want to restrict access to the folders via url .i.e i don't want people to have access to my image folder using a url like this::

http://website/all_images/

all images is the folder that contains the image folder .. i tried using a `htaccess` file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^CI_system.*
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/index.php?/$1 [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|all_images)
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
  </IfModule>
```

the rewrite  condition  for the index.php works well but i still get access to all my folders via the url

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable folders to be viewed, just add empty index.html file, but if you try to protect images from being viewed then your website wont be able to find them too

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create an index file under that folder. In this way no will will be able to view images under that folder.

You can make this file call a function that says "access denied" or whatever you need.

Comment: @BrandonS and @luci tnks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Options -Indexes in your htaccess file will stop directory viewing no extra files needed. and if you want to stop direct image viewing i.e. myweb.com/all_images/coolpic.jpg then all you have to do is (since your base is / you can use the whole one below):

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?myweb.com/.*$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

All you would have to change is the line with your web address in it and add all of your file types to the last rewrite rule (seperating each with a pipe |) and then this will cover all of the angles you have discussed 100%.